# Jest: How to set offsetWidth with dom

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

How to set [offsetWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth) because `HTMLElement.offsetWidth` is read-only property.
I have the following error when I try to force the value which is expected.

> TypeError: Cannot set property offsetWidth of [object HTMLElement] which has only a getter

Then I tried the following, but it doesn't work. I have no errors too:

```
    document.querySelector('.a').setAttribute('offsetWidth', 600);
```

Answer (score 1):

Never mind I found the solution. You can use `style.width` :

```
document.querySelector('.a').style.width = '600px';
```